# reading a subset of files within a folder using R

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I'm quite new to R and am looking to build an R script that takes a csv file containing 3 elements:

```
Id
Type
Filename
```

The contents of the DataFrame look something like:

```
14261336    5   Test1.xml
16767594    8   Test2.xml
13601470    7   Test3.xml
12963658    5   Test4.xml
17771952    6   Test5.xml
```

I've tried to use the following code to get the filenames, and then use these to be able to parse the XML, but I seem to be hitting a bit of a wall (down to my inexperience with R):

```
headerNames <- c('Id','Type','Filename')
GetNames <- read.csv(file= 'c:/temp/XML/myXMLFiles.csv', header = FALSE, col.names = headerNames) #

list(c(GetNames[3])) %>%
  map(read_xml)
```

The outcome is that I get the message:
Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list"

Can one of you experts point me in the right direction please?

Many Thanks

Comment: You'll need to break your filenames out of a list so that read_xml() is getting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally only read data from a string. Furthermore, to read xml, you will need the xmlParse() from xml-library:

```
library(XML)  # install it with install.packages("XML") if needed
files_inp <- as.character(GetNames[,3]) # you will need the filenames as character

for (f in files_inp) {
  assign(paste0("file",f), xmlParse(file = f))  # I never read XML files, but that should work! :-)
}
```

Your output data should be variables named file1, file2, ...

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, should have included that I had XML2 library loaded. I'll look at this approach. Thanks